# How to change paper size in PHPWord

Tags: php, phpword

***How to Change Paper Size in phpword?***

I Want to Change the paper size to Legal paper (8.5 in. by 14 in). I cannot find the option in the documentation. I am not sure on what to apply the rule, and no ''paper'' or ''size'' seems related to this in the documentation.

(https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Does anybody knows if it is possible to set the desired paper size on a document?

Comment: You should reopen it as I have the right answer, I would love to post an answer, this is how I googled it, and found nothing except this, and it is closed and answer is not correct, I'd like to post the right answer for future references!

Answer (score 2):

By default, `section` element has the `orientation` property in the `style` array. It is set to landscape or portrait, and these are default values for the page width and height. However, you can set them how you want.

> orientation: Page orientation (portrait, which is default, or landscape).
>
> pageSizeH. Page height in twip. Implicitly defined by orientation option. Any changes are discouraged.
>
> pageSizeW. Page width in twip. Implicitly defined by orientation option. Any changes are discouraged.

Here is a link to it:

https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html

Now, here is an example of how I used it in my code in order to make it work:

```
<?php
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection([
    'pageSizeH' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(11),
    'pageSizeW' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Converter::inchToTwip(8.5)
]);
```

You have the static method in the converter class to calculate the ''Twip'' unit, which is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the paper style `size` property. Please refer to the [documentation](http://phpoffice.github.io/PHPWord/docs/master/classes/PhpOffice.PhpWord.Style.Paper.html).

Comment: $document->size->setSize('Legal');  I do not know how to use the documentation. help me

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:  (EDIT, added namespace for class)

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Paper;

$paper = new Paper();
$paper->setSize('Letter');  // or 'Legal', 'A4' ...

$section = $doc->addSection([
    'pageSizeW' => $paper->getWidth(),
    'pageSizeH' => $paper->getHeight(),
]);
```

I agree it seems to be missing from the docs.

Comment: What is the namespace for the `Paper` class?

Comment: PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Paper