# PHPOffice/PHPWord - How to setup paper size with landscape orientation

Tags: php, phpword, phpoffice

I did follow this post: [How to change paper size in PHPWord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43189689/how-to-change-paper-size-in-phpword)

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$phpword = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$paper = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Paper();
$paper->setSize('Letter'); 

$section = $phpword->addSection(array('pageSizeW' => $paper->getWidth(), 'pageSizeH' => $paper->getHeight()));

$section->addText("Hello World!");

$phpword->save('./test.docx', 'Word2007');

?>
```

It will create file with Letter paper and Portrait layout

I change to this:

```
$section = $phpword->addSection(array('orientation' => 'landscape'));
```

It generated file with Landscape layout but is **A4** paper size.

How to generate file with Letter size + Landscape layout?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using like this: `$phpword->addSection(array('pageSizeW' => $paper->getWidth(), 'pageSizeH' => $paper->getHeight(), 'orientation' => 'landscape'));`

Comment: @Saud it worked. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I'm posting it as an answer so that others can also benefit from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the orientation key in the array with width and height:

```
$section = $phpword->addSection(array(
    'pageSizeW' => $paper->getWidth(), 
    'pageSizeH' => $paper->getHeight(), 
    'orientation' => 'landscape'
));
```